# Multiple parties must encrypt and get the same result

Tags: encryption, hash, aes

Hopefully this question is not too simple - I did some research but with encryption I really don't want to make a mistake.

Our scenario is that multiple groups need to encrypt a number and arrive at the same result.

This is because they want to use credit card numbers to search for documents, but we are only willing to store an encrypted version of the number as a search index.

I believe a one way hashing function of some sort would be best, salted somehow.

Would this be secure, given that:

- We are storing a masked version of each number too (roughly half the number is visible, i.e. the non-personal details)
- An attacker could have an account and therefore know their own plaintext

AES-256 was discussed as it's fairly standard in the banking industry but I don't know if it's appropriate here - we would be unable to use a random salt or initialisation vector.

It may be better to accept the full number as a search term and encrypt server side, but for various reasons I don't believe this will be possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Do they need to always arrive at different results when they start with different numbers? $\hspace{1.22 in}$

Comment: Yes - but for now we can assume a very low chance hash collision is probably acceptable, as users can view the documents to find what they are looking for.

Comment: Do you want to defend against a brute-force search by an attacker _who knows the system-wide key_ $\hspace{.01 in}$? $\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: all you would need is a collision proof hash

Comment: with half the number visible you have 8 digits that are unknown (for a 16 digit number), quite easy to brute force

Comment: Yes that's the problem, a brute force check for a small string of 8 characters. I was wondering whether something with a work factor like bcrypt makes this less of a problem.

Comment: Are the hashes (and the 8 digits stored in plain) public information, or can you keep them hidden on your own servers and only allow on-line existence queries? That would significantly affect the options you'll have.

Comment: Something that also uses a lot of memory, namely scrypt, is the only thing that would help at all. $\hspace{.52 in}$

Comment: Since you're dealing with credit cards, this [question on Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/1017) may be of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your approach is absolutely not secure.**

The problem is mathematical, not technical. The search space is simply too small. There are only a finite possible number of values for an account number, and all an attacker has to do is try them all. If his output matches your stored value, he learns the account number. The technology choice of hashing with SHA-256 or encrypting with AES makes no difference.

Account numbers are 16 digits, so it looks like an attacker has to test $10^{16}$ possible values. To a specially crafted application running on a massively parallel processor like a graphics card, that's no longer a big number. ([Machines capable of executing 348 billion hashes per second are now being built by hobbyists.](http://hackaday.com/2011/06/01/gpu-password-cracking-made-easy/)) But account numbers  don't have that much uncertainty. Valid BIN numbers reduce the attackers job by a factor of a hundred thousand.  In your case you said you are keeping half the number visible (masking the other half), so the search space drops to $10^{8}$ possible tests.  I can also use the Luhn check digit to recover an additional hidden digit, meaning I only have to try $10^{7}$ possible numbers.

And I'm just making a guess here, based on the statement that you're revealing "roughly half" the number.  I assume you're revealing the last four digits, because you probably print those on your receipts and don't consider them secret.  And I assume you're revealing the first four digits, because they're the Bank Identification Number (BIN).  But BINs are actually six assigned digits, and given the first four I can probably determine the next two with a fairly high degree of certainty (there are far less than the 999,999 valid BINs suggested by the range).  So knowing 10 digits plus the Luhn algorithm gives me $10^{5}$ uncertain digits.  That's only a hundred thousand attempts, and I can spin through that many tests in a second on my PC without even invoking the graphics card!

The secure approach is to use a service to replace the account number with a non-mathematically-derived value, commonly called a token. Inside the secure service is where you would place the encrypted account number and perform your look-ups. An auto-generated sequence number is fine for this. Instead of giving each group the algorithm to look up an account number on their own, you grant them access to the service.

The service would need to be strongly protected against unauthenticated and unauthorized access, with audit logs tracing whoever is using it. If someone wants to run a million tests, at least you have the chance to detect them.

Also see the PCI Guidelines for advice on handling "multi-use tokens" which is this type of use.

Comment: The OP could also use format-preserving encryption, which gives decent provable security when encrypting very short strings. The paper 'Format-preserving Encryption by Bellare et al. is a good starting point.

Comment: FPE is good if you're trying to fit 16 encrypted bytes in the place of 16 cleartext bytes.  But that's not the problem they're trying to solve.  They're trying to produce identical encrypted values for each account number, as he stated that multiple teams need to "arrive at the same result", so they could correlate or index encrypted account numbers.  That requirement precludes random IVs or salts that would prevent such an attack.

Comment: So basically, "that's not the problem they're trying to solve, except that it is."$\hspace{.02 in}$? $\hspace{1.61 in}$

Comment: No, it answers a question about encryption, but doesn't solve the security problem of the possible account number space being easily searchable.

Comment: Does your suggestion come any closer to solving that security problem? $\:$

Comment: Yes.  To be secure, you can't distribute the encryption key or hash method (like he asked.)  The cryptographic operation has to remain in a tightly controlled environment, like an oracle, and all access must be granted through a service that authenticates and authorizes its users.  It still can't prevent the attack, but you could possibly detect one or trace one.

Comment: Even bulking up the attack using scrypt or other make-work algorithm isn't enough to protect it.  There are only 100,000 possible values that need to be tested if he's truly preserving 8 bytes of "non-personal details".  It's just not a hard problem to brute force.

Comment: Since one wouldn't distribute the format-preserving encryption key, one could still detect such an attack. $\;$

Comment: I think you're trying to solve the problem inside the oracle.  But because it's a trusted and secure environment, he can use AES, SHA, FPE, it doesn't matter.  What matters greatly is what is exposed to the users.  If they are given a key and algorithm, as he asked for, it's game over.  If they are given credentials and a service, he retains auditable control, which is critical for PCI compliance.

Comment: Because it's a trusted and secure environment, there _might_ be a relevant limit on the amount of memory available to it. $\:$ If there isn't, then one could use scrypt with a secret salt as a second line of defense, especially if what's revealed is different from what you were guessing. $\;\;\;$

Comment: Admittedly, the FPE would help very little here. $\:$

Comment: Thanks guys - the assumptions above sound correct to me. I thought about it overnight and the attacker only needs to check a few digits as you've said. I had thought a significant work factor (e.g. 1 second to compute a hash) could help, but then again - any attacker will have access to more power than us, it's not future proof, and we have processing deadlines which they don't. I will read the information on multi-use tokens, thanks for the pointer, I didn't know what to look for earlier as I'm far from an expert.

Comment: @NickP, the other concern is to view this from an attacker's viewpoint. He doesn't care if he gets 100% perfect results.  If he can steal only 10% of your account numbers, that could be millions.  Certainly enough to steal from.

Comment: Yes that's true. We'll need to talk about this more here, it sounds like a tokeniser service is the best way forward though.

Comment: @NickP, there are a few more details to consider. Make sure the GetToken(cardNo) service is as securely controlled as the GetCardNo(token) service, in order to prevent this attack. Also, my earlier statement about using sequence numbers as tokens could leak information about "unseen" vs "previously seen" numbers, so I wouldn't use sequence numbers as tokens.

Comment: Thanks John - I definitely am not planning to implement this myself any time soon. I'll wait and see what decision is made.